# How to use an array to take command line arguments?

Tags: c++, arrays, cmd

So I'm trying to use cmd to take arguments while starting the program, but I keep running into issues from converting the variables from char to int, so they can be used with the rest of the program. Thanks for the help ahead of time.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int n = 0, a = 0, b = 0, func = 0, choice = 0;
    double w;
    if(argc < 10)
    {
        cout << "The Program requires -f <Function> -a <Starting Point> -b <Ending Point> -m <Method> -n <Number of slices>" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        int func, a, b, choice, n;
        int i;
        for(int i = 1; i < argc - 1; i+=2)
        {
                if(argv[i] == "-f"){
                    func = *argv[i + 1];}
                else if(argv[i] == "-a"){
                    a = *argv[i + 1];}
                else if(argv[i] == "-b"){
                    b = *argv[i + 1];}
                else if(argv[i] == "-m"){
                    choice = *argv[i + 1];}
                else if(argv[i] == "-n"){
                    n = *argv[i + 1];}
                else {
                    cout << "Input is Invalid" << endl;
                    exit(0);}
                cout << argv[i] << endl;
        }
        w = (b-a)/double(n);
        next(n, a, b, w, func, choice);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

edit: So I have restructured my code to look like that above and it does compile, but I'm getting only the else statement. Such as when is start the program using a line like: ./a3 -f 5 -a 1 -b 10 -m 3 -n 100. I'm not sure why the program reverts to the else statement "input is Invalid" instead of the other if, if else statements.

Comment: What is the problem? What is the output of the compiler; which errors did you get?

Comment: Why do you redefine your variables `char* func, a, b, choice, n;`?

Comment: `char* func, a, b, choice, n` should be `int func, a, b, choice, n`.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you have to start with:

```
int n = 0, a = 0, b = 0, func = 0, choice = 0;
```

and then you have a character pointer to an integer type defined as

```
  char* func, a, b, choice, n;
```

I believe in the standard, pointer should point to their type and that is your problem.

Solution:

I guess you could use cast it to an char before you assign the ptrs..

Answer (score 0):

you have problem with string comparing.

```
if(argv[i] == "-f")
```

don't check if argv[i] is equal to "-f" it check if the pointer value is the same as the pointer to the constants string "-f" with is wrong.
you should use string compare methods like strcmp.

also is all flags require value why the loop is:

```
for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
    if(i + 1 != argc)
```

because it pairs you can write it as:

```
for(int i = 1 ; i < argc - 1; i += 2)
```